# В if постоянно работает только первая часть блока .В чем проблема?

Tags: java, android

If постоянно =  `Toast.makeText(MainActivity2_3.this,("!="),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

```
public static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
           public static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
            };
```

//

```
if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // We don't have permission so prompt the user
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity2_3.this,("!="),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {     Toast.makeText(MainActivity2_3.this,("="),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
```

Comment: в коде не видно что у вас за переменная `permission` - отсюда вывод, что и с чем вы сравниваете? Посмотрите примеры в интернете - там их очень много

Comment: Кто вас так учит вопросы писать? Что вообще означает первое предложение?

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо  Andrey Mihalev

Работает для меня!

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS_STORAGE, REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity2_3.this,("нет"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            else
            {     Toast.makeText(MainActivity2_3.this,("есть"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
```